# Double newlines following function definitions

Tags: code-formatting, clang-format

Is it possible to use clang-format to have double newlines between function definitions:

```
void func1() 
{
    return;
}


void func2() 
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: You can have even 3 new lines between function definitions

Answer (score 1):

`clang-format` does not have an option controlling the number of newlines after the function definition. However, it does have an option, `MaxEmptyLinesToKeep`, which will keep it from undoing your two empty lines. So, you will have to cook up some way of doing this through your editor and `clang-format` with `MaxEmptyLinesToKeep` set to `2`, or higher, will respect your decision.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether the IDE can insert these lines automatically, I don't believe so. You can have any number of lines but only by manually entering them.