# Is there a way to add two line breaks between two functions in clang format?

Tags: c++, clang-format

Basically what I want is:

```cpp
void func1() 
{
   cout << a;
}


void func2() 
{
   count << a;
}
```

Is there a `.clang-format` option to do this? If not, can it be done through some script with clang?

Comment: [Double newlines following function definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28826390)